# WCF http binding error: The content type text/html does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a WPF client which consumes a WCF service which is self hosted in a Winforms app. The client is accessing the service server via a VPN connection. At first initialisation, the client app catches an exception from the service:

```
There was a problem reaching the service. 
The content type of text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml;charset=utf-8).
If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is
implemented properly.
```

The service is running without issue and this issue only appears when connecting via VPN, not from my Visual Studio development environment which is on the same domain as the service VM:

[image]

This exception only occurs on first initialisation, when  I run the client app again, the issue is resolved & everything runs as expected. Here is my service app config:

```
  <services>
  <service name="IsesService.IsesService">                           
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IsesService.IIsesService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>     
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://EMEA-DIIS01v:8082"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

 <behavior>         
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />          
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>

 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp"
             useDefaultWebProxy="false"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
              >
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxDepth="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>      
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And client side:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IIsesService" useDefaultWebProxy="false"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://emea-diis01v:8082/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IIsesService" contract="ServiceReference.IIsesService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IIsesService" />
    </client>      
</system.serviceModel>
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0):

Check with [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) what is the content of the first response.
It is probably different when you use VPN.

Comment: Not getting anything from Fiddler in the browser unfortunately. I enabled trace logging on the WCF service but it doesn't log the problem, just logs the last successful method call  before it drops out. I think this is an issue related to the VPN and out of the scope of the .NET code.